# String to Integer (atoi) [Leetcode] gave wrong answer?

Tags: swift, algorithm, atoi

[String to Integer (atoi)](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/)

This problem is implement atoi to convert a string to an integer.

When test input = "   +0 123"

My code return  = 123

But why expected answer = 0?

======================

And if test input = "   +0123"

My code return  = 123

Now expected answer = 123

So is that answer wrong?

Comment: You have not shown your code. I'm guessing you are discarding all whitespace characters, so therefore " +0 123" becomes "+0123", which is a valid number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is expected result as it said

> Requirements for atoi:
>   The function first discards as many whitespace characters as necessary until the first non-whitespace character is found. **Then, starting from this character, takes an optional initial plus or minus sign followed by as many numerical digits as possible, and interprets them as a numerical value**.

Your first test case has a space in between two different digit groups, and atoi only consider the first group which is '0' and convert into integer